# How to Disable cookiechoices.js (Blogger)

Tags: cookies, blogger

I need to disable cookiechoices.js, i trying to add JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    cookieChoices = {};   </script>

&lt;!--</body>--&gt;&lt;/body&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea please read [this](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6253244?hl=en) but if you want to disable cookies notification in European Union countries add this script in the `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    cookieChoices = {};
</script>
```

Your code will disable cookies notification. but you can't remove `cookiechoices.js` from blogger by `&lt;!--</body>--&gt;&lt;/body&gt;`

Comment: What do you want to do? disabling cookies notification or removing cookiechoices.js

Comment: removing cookieschoices.js for improving pagespeed

Comment: You can't remove it. there is no way till now.